# Finding the owner and group of a file (as a string)

Tags: c, linux

I am trying to get a C string of the owner and group of a file, After I do a `stat()` I get the user ID and group ID, but how do I get the name?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`getgrgid()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getgrgid.html) to get the group name and [`getpwuid()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getpwuid.html) to get the user name:

```
#include <pwd.h>
#include <grp.h>

/* ... */

struct group *grp;
struct passwd *pwd;

grp = getgrgid(gid);
printf("group: %s\n", grp->gr_name);

pwd = getpwuid(uid);
printf("username: %s\n", pwd->pw_name);
```

Comment: Note that `getgrgid()` and `getpwuid()` can return `NULL` if the relevant entry is missing, in which case you should probably just convert the numeric ID to a string with `sprintf()`.

Answer (score 3):

Try using getpwuid();

http://linux.die.net/man/3/getpwuid